# Does "to_char()" use more CPU than "BETWEEN" in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm looking for the most processor-friendly SQL statement between the following ones.

SQL should return in both cases: the count of records where `"last_time_hit"` field is today.

**Statement 1:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM chrono 
WHERE to_char(last_time_hit, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

**Statement 2:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM chrono 
WHERE last_time_hit BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 second'
```

Comment: CPU is not a problem here, but IO. Hence the original "the one that uses less CPU" is an X-Y Problem

Comment: performance may also be gained be replacing `SELECT COUNT(*)` with `SELECT COUNT(<pk_column>)`, *assuming the table has a primary key.*

Comment: @HaleemurAli what makes you thinking so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sense, yes.  The second query can make use of an index on `last_time_hit`, which can make the query run much, much faster.  Even without an index in this case, it is a good habit to use `BETWEEN` for other situations when one is available.

In general, the use of functions precludes the use of an index -- except for expression-based indexes.   (It is possible that Postgres would do a full scan on an index in the first case; this is slightly more efficient than scanning the table, but not the big win that you usually get when using an index.)